# MySql REGEXP - how to extract 7 digit value from URL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a link (shown below ) field in Table A with values like:

> - http://test.abc.com/carrier/CA-9265/2360283/?id=41352626&src=j2w&eid=72-201301190212-88381790
> - http://test.abc.com/sub/carrier/CA-12656/4322830/?id=41352626&src=j2w&eid=72-201301190212-88381790

I need to extract 7 digit code from the links. The code:

1 - is always 7 digit not containing character.

2 - is always contains `'/carrier/'` and comes 1 section away from `'/carrier/'`.

In the above links the code are 2360283 and 4322830.

Please suggest a select query with `RegExp`.

Thanks,

Comment: Something like `carrier/.*/\([\d]{7}\)[^\d]` ("seven digits followed by not-a-digit") should give you what you want... (in the `()` expression... recovered with `\1`. Some dialects of regexp don't need the `\ ` before the `(` ) , and assuming your version of regexp doesn't make `/` special (otherwise, escape it - i.e. use `\/`).

Comment: could you have `.../carrier/something/7-digit/somethingelse/?id=blah` ? or is "carrier" always the last "directory" name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY

```
$str = 'http://test.abc.com/carrier/CA-9265/2360283/?id=41352626&src=j2w&...';  
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX($str,'/',-2),'/',1)
// return 2360283
```

Read [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for more

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you do not know where `carrier` nor the "7-digit code" will appear then you would have to calculate `/carrier/` position and use relative position to that, but only on relevant rows to the pattern

### [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3028f/14)

```
select 
    substring_index(substring_index(link,
                '/',
                find_in_set('carrier',
                        replace(replace(link, ',', '{'), /* { is any weird character */
                            '/',
                            ',')) + 2), /*  +2 => 1 section away from carrier */
        '/',
        - 1)  as SEVENDIGITCODE
from 
    TableA
where
    link regexp '/carrier.*/[0-9]{7}/'
```